# How to deal with form error message in django?

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I have a `FormView` and when I rendering this form as `{{ form.as_table }}` in my template, it shows error message right under each field like this (only when I type wrong value on each field) :
[image]
(Ignore their arrangement, please)

Since I want to show this form nicely, so I edit my template and add some css on it :

```
<table id="signup-table">
    <col width="30%">
    <col width="70%">
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.username.label_tag }}</td>
        <td class="value">{{ signup_form.username }}</td>
        {{ signup_form.errors.username }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.password1.label_tag }}</td>
        <td class="value">{{ signup_form.password1 }}</td>
        {{ signup_form.errors.password1 }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.password2.label_tag }}</td>
        <td class="value">{{ signup_form.password2 }}</td>
        {{ signup_form.errors.password2 }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.name.label_tag }}</td>
        <td class="value">{{ signup_form.name }}</td>
        {{ signup_form.errors.name }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.gender.label_tag }}</td>
        <td class="value">{{ signup_form.gender }}</td>
        {{ signup_form.errors.gender }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.birth.label_tag }}</td>
        <td class="value">{{ signup_form.birth }}</td>
        {{ signup_form.errors.birth }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.phone_number.label_tag }}</td>
        <td class="value">{{ signup_form.phone_number }}</td>
        {{ signup_form.errors.phone_number }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.job.label_tag }}</td>
        <td class="value">{{ signup_form.job }}</td>
        {{ signup_form.errors.job}}
    </tr>
</table>
```

And now it shows error messages on the top of the form.

[image]
In this case, I want to show error message right under each field. How can I do this?

Thanks.

**Edit**

Chrome  `View page source` : error is right below each field.

```
<table id="signup-table">
    <col width="30%">
    <col width="70%">
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag"><label for="id_username">아이디:</label></td>
        <td class="value"><input id="id_username" maxlength="20" name="username" placeholder="알파벳, 숫자만 가능(4~20자)" type="text" value="wrongid" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag"><label for="id_password1">비밀번호:</label></td>
        <td class="value"><input id="id_password1" maxlength="20" name="password1" placeholder="영문,숫자 반드시 포함(6~20자)" type="password" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag"><label for="id_password2">비밀번호 확인:</label></td>
        <td class="value"><input id="id_password2" maxlength="20" name="password2" placeholder="비밀번호 확인" type="password" /></td>
        <ul class="errorlist"><li>비밀번호가 너무 짧습니다. 최소 6 문자를 포함해야 합니다.</li><li>패스워드가 너무 일상적인 단어입니다.</li></ul>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag"><label for="id_name">이 름:</label></td>
        <td class="value"><input id="id_name" maxlength="4" name="name" type="text" /></td>
        <ul class="errorlist"><li>이 항목을 채워주십시오.</li></ul>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-tag"><label for="id_gender">성 별:</label></td>
        <td class="value"><select id="id_gender" name="gender">
        .
        .
        .
```

Chrome  `inspect` :  all errors are top of the form

I don't know why they are different....

(I didn't have any `css` to `errorlist`)

[image]

Comment: I think this is more a CSS question - can you please include the CSS and the html that's output by the error?

Comment: I edit it. I didn't touch any `css` about `errorlist`

Comment: Can you include a bit more of the template before the form?  It looks like you're rendering the error list before the `table` tag.   Also note that you seem to have 2 unclosed `col` tags which won't help things.

Comment: I didn't have any control on `errorlist` because I use `Django forms`. It just appears and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You calling `errors` from form directly but you should call it from each form field.

```
...
<tr>
    <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.name.label_tag }}</td>
    <td class="value">{{ signup_form.name }}</td>
    {{ signup_form.name.errors }}
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.gender.label_tag }}</td>
    <td class="value">{{ signup_form.gender }}</td>
    {{ signup_form.gender.erros }}
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label-tag">{{ signup_form.birth.label_tag }}</td>
    <td class="value">{{ signup_form.birth }}</td>
    {{ signup_form.birth.errors }}
</tr>
...
```

Also you migth want to add `{{ signup_form.non_field_errors }}` at the top of the form.
[docs about errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages)